# Spring Batch - Conditional Read from database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

This is my first code in SpringBatch using SpringBoot, I am implementing a sample usecase.

This is the exact pseudo-code i want to implement in SpringBatch, can you please help:

It's not feasible to fetch all hotel details(>3 million records) at one shot and process it, so i decided to fetch 1 hotel(50,000 records) at a time and process it and write to DB. Want to repeat this step for each and every hotelID as described below. Does this use-case suitable for SpringBatch ?

```
List<Integer> allHotelIDs = execute("select distinct(hotelid) from Hotels"); 

List items = new Arraylist();
allHotelIDs.forEach(hotelID -> {
    Object item = itemReader.jdbcReader(hotelID, dataSource);
    Object processedItem = itemProcessor.process(item);
    items.add(processedItem);
});
itemWriter.write(items);
```

I am able to pass only 1 hotelid, how can i invoke it multiple times for all list hotels ?

```
@Bean
Job job(JobBuilderFactory jbf, StepBuilderFactory sbf, DBReaderWriter step1) throws Exception {

  Step db2db = sbf.get("db-db").<Table, List<Tendency>>chunk(1000)
      .reader(step1.jdbcReader(hotelID, dataSource))
      .processor(processor())
      .writer(receivableWriter()).build();

  return jbf.get("etl").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(db2db).build();
}
```

Reader code:

```
@Configuration
public class DBReader {
  @Bean
  public ItemReader<Table> jdbcReader(Integer hotelID, DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Table>().dataSource(dataSource).name("jdbc-reader")
        .sql("SELECT * FROM Hotels where hotelid ="+hotelID).rowMapper((rs, i) -> {
          return read().db(rs, "Hotels");
        }).build();
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a common pattern in SB and is called 'driving query' (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders)

Comment: I second Luca's comment. This is a typical use case for the driving query pattern. You need a reader that reads only the hotel IDs and a processor that queries the details of each hotel.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, Have done changes as you suggested, getting desired output, can you please guide me how to call process method in a multi threaded fashion, suppose I have 5 hotel id's, how can I call process method for those 5 id's at a time instead of sequentially?

Comment: For that you can use the `AsyncItemProcessor` (in conjunction with `AsyncItemWriter`) as explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#asynchronous-processors

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info.